# Promise findOneAsync variable = {"isFulfilled":false,"isRejected":false}?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, promise, bluebird

Utilizing Bluebird to Promisfy Mongoose, I have a Promise.map(function with a series of if/else for looping through an array to see if a reference doc exists, else create one..

Assigning the product of findOneAsync to a variable, to then assign 'variable._id' to a new doc in the making (the main promise), the console logs `{"isFulfilled":false,"isRejected":false}`

*Here's a snippet:*

```
for (i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
    var existingItem = Models.Items.findOneAsync({ item: items[i] });
    console.log( "existingItem : ");
    console.log( JSON.stringify(existingItem) );
    console.log( "existingItem._id : " + existingItem._id );
```

*Here's a log:*

```
existingItem : 
{"isFulfilled":false,"isRejected":false}
existingItem._id : undefined
```

Why might the `existingItem` variable be pending for the Model.Item.findOneAsync..?

Comment: I don't see you assigning a value to `variable._id`. Are we supposed to imagine what your code looks like?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your question is not really clear, but my question to you would be: why would `existingItem` *not* be pending right after you retrieved it?

Do you understand how to use promises? Most of the time you need to get at their resolved values using `.then()` or other promise manipulation functions:

```
var existingItem = Models.Items.findOneAsync({ item: items[i] });
existingItem.then(function (value) {
    console.log( "existingItem : ");
    console.log( JSON.stringify(existingItem) );
    console.log( JSON.stringify(value); );
    console.log( "existingItem._id : " + existingItem._id );
});
```

Comment: Appreciate the pointer. Here's where this stands: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28482021/promise-map-not-finshing-because-subsequent-promise-join-finishes-first-promise

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait until the promise gets resolved (or rejected).
You can use any one of the following two ways:

**1. By 'awaiting' to get the final state of the promise as follows:**

```
var existingItem = await Models.Items.findOneAsync({ item: items[i] });
```

**2. By handling the promise using '.then' handler as follows:**

```
return Models.Items.findOneAsync({ item: items[i] })
    .then(function(existingItem) {
        console.log("existingItem", existingItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
return Promise.each(items, function(item) {
  return Models.Items.findOneAsync({item: item}).then(function(existingItem) {
    console.log("existingItem", existingItem);
  });
});
```

Comment: Is there a better pattern than this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28482021/promise-map-not-finshing-because-subsequent-promise-join-finishes-first-promise

Answer (score 0):

findOneAsync() simply hasn't finished running yet when you start writing the console.logs.

Also complicating things, it looks like `findOneAsync()` is returning a Promise (status is neither fulfilled nor rejected yet at the point you are writing logs).

So if you want to store and log the found item, you need to

1. Wait for the Promise to resolve by using its `.then()` fucntion,
   and
2. Retrieve the found item from the "resolved value". `findOneAsync()` should pass the found item object as a parameter to its
   `resolve()` function (i.e. somewhere inside `findOneAsync()` there would be: `resolve(foundItem);`).

Assuming all that, this should work:

```
    for (i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
        var findPromise = Models.Items.findOneAsync({ item: items[i] });
        //the next line won't run until findOneAsync finishes
        findPromise.then(resolveResult => {
            var existingItem = resolveResult;
            console.log( "existingItem : ");
            console.log( JSON.stringify(existingItem) );
            console.log( "existingItem._id : " + existingItem._id );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is, your are **not waiting** until the operation is finished. You are logging before `findOne` operation is finished.

You can  use either `then` or `await` to wait until the operation finishes.

- `then`

  ```
  Item.findOne({ where: { id: your_id } })
      .then(result => console.log(result))
  ```
- `await` function must be prefixed with `async` key, but this code is much cleaner

  ```
  const result = await Item.findOne({ where: { id: your_id  } })
  console.log(result)
  ```